# How do I fetch HTML of URL using Vapor Swift?

Tags: swift, request, response, vapor

In one of my routes, I want to fetch HTML from a different site. `https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/content/ documents` support for JSON and such but I couldn't find anything on raw HTML.

```swift
request.client.get(URI(string: "https://example.com/")).map { (response: ClientResponse) -> String? in
    if response.status == .ok && response.content.contentType == .html {
        return response.content... // How do I get raw html?
    }

    return nil
}
```

How do I get the raw HTML from the client response?

Comment: take a look at `response.body`, it is what you're looking for :)

Comment: @imike `Cannot convert value of type 'ByteBuffer?' to specified type 'String'`. How do I get the HTML as a String?

Comment: `String(buffer: byteBuffer)`

Comment: @imike have you considered adding this as an answer?

Comment: nope, I'm just glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, depending on which `String` initializer you happen to fancy. Note that to use any of the following methods, you will need to unwrap the response body first:

```
guard let body = response.body else {
    throw Abort(.internalServerError)
}
```

The first way is using the `ByteBuffer.readString` method.

```
guard let html = body.readString(length: body.readableBytes) else {
    throw Abort(.internalServerError)
}
```

Another way is to use the `String(decoding:as:)` initializer, which can be used to convert any collection of `UInt8` integers to a `String`:

```
let html = String(decoding: body.readableBytesView, as: UTF8.self)
```

Anf finally, you can use the `String(buffer:)` initializer that @iMike suggested.

```
let html = String(buffer: body)
```

Keep in mind that the `.readBytes` method will increment the `.readIndex` of the `ByteBuffer`, while the `String` initializers won't. Though I imagine that this doesn't really matter in your case.